# Load Numerical Column with Variable Comma

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

I'm using sqlldr to load a file which has a numerical value as one of its fields.

The problem is that in some of the records the number has commas whereas in other, it doesn't.

So doing something like

```
num "to_number(:num, '999,999,999.99')",
```

loads the records with commas but not those without commas and doing

```
num "to_number(:num)",
```

loads only those without commas.

Is there a way to tell Oracle (sqlldr) that the comma is optional?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you go:

```
SQL> desc loadertst;
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 COL1                                               NUMBER

SQL> !cat loadertst.ctl
load data
infile *
into table loadertst
fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"'
(
col1 "to_number(replace(:col1,',',''))"
)
begindata
"123456"
"1,2,3,4,5,6"

SQL> !sqlldr phil/phil control=loadertst.ctl

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Thu Nov 29 23:33:17 2012

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 2

SQL> select count(*) from loadertst;

  COUNT(*)
----------
         2

SQL>
```

Obviously you may need to fiddle with the `fields terminated by ',' enclosed by '"'` part to suit your data.

Comment: OK, this works; I ended up doing something similar before seeing your answer. I guess, at first, my brain had been looking for a way of using the format model to 'logically' say that the value may or may not contain commas.